# ERROR: opus not found using pkg-config in msys64 on Windows

Tags: ffmpeg, msys2, msys, pkg-config, pacman-package-manager

I'm trying to build ffmpeg.

I downloaded msys2 x64 from the official website. This is the latest version.
Executed "pacman-Syu", rebooted msys and executed "pacman-Su".

In your file build_ffmpeg_win.sh ffmpeg installs the following packages using pacman:

```
pacman --noconfirm -Sy
pacman --noconfirm -S msys/make
pacman --noconfirm -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-opus
pacman --noconfirm -S pkg-config
pacman --noconfirm -S diffutils
pacman --noconfirm -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config
```

Then I run "pacman -Qet" in order to get the list of packages:

```
$ pacman -Qet
base 2020.12-1
diffutils 3.8-1
make 4.3-1
mingw-w64-x86_64-opus 1.3.1-4
pkg-config 0.29.2-4
```

The opus package is installed.

However, when I try to run "build_ffmpeg_win.sh", then I get the following error at the stage *./configure*: "**ERROR: opus not found using pkg-config**"

The following folders and files are located in the "msys64\mingw64\lib" folder:

```
pkgconfig (folder)
libopus.a
libopus.dll.a
```

There is an opus.pc file in the msys64\mingw64\lib\pkgconfig folder, the contents of which refer to /mingw64/lib and /mingw64/include.
pkg-config knows about opus, but for some reason this error occurs during ./configure.

How can I solve this problem?